# istream is not splitting the input from text file correctly

Tags: c++, codeblocks, istream

I have just started learning C++ and currently I am having an issue with the use of `istream` where I am trying to read in a text file and initialize the 'split' values to the variables.

For example in my text file, the contents are:

```
P1001 john 3500
```

And in my `person.cpp`, the `istream` function are as follows:

```
Person::Person(const char *id, const char *uname, unsigned sal)
{
    strncpy(pid, id, 5);
    strncpy(name, uname, 5);
    salary= sal;
}

istream & operator >> (istream &input, Person &p)
{
    input >> p.pid >> p.name >> p.salary;
    return input;
}
```

In my output file, I am expecting to see:

```
ID: P1001
Name: john
Salary: 3500
```

However, I am seeing:

```
ID: P1001john
Name: john
Salary: 3500
```

I tried inserting in `pid[5] = '\0'` in hopes that this will break up the value, but it does not seems to be working. Even so, I had thought that `istream` will 'split' the string value by the spaces... if so why is it the `pid` comprises of both the id and name value?

I am using codeblocks, tried cleaning and rebuilding the workspace but to no avail results. Appreciate any insights.

Comment: Please add the class definition of Person. 
It also looks like, you are using `const char *` / `char*` outside of constexpr Stmt's. Don't do this. Use std::string instead.

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that your class definition says `char pid[5];`. Note that a five-character id requires six `char`s, and writing outside an array has undefined behaviour.

Comment: please provide a [mre]